# GET request returns Error 404 through Axios, but works in Postman?

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, expo

I'm developing a mobile app using the [GiantBomb API](https://www.giantbomb.com/api/). I'm developing using React Native and Expo. I'm currently working on a screen in the app which takes the unique GUID of a game selected from a list and displays the relevant information. It gets the data it needs through an Axios GET request.

Earlier screens in the app retrieve different data from the API through the same method with no problems, and when putting the same request used in the app into Postman - using the same GUID - I get the data I expect returned.

For some reason, the GET request made through Axios returns a 404 error while the same GET request made through Postman gives me the information I need.

This is the Axios request made in the app:

```
    axios({
      url: "https://www.giantbomb.com/api/game/"+{gameId}+"/?api_key=[API_KEY]",
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then(response => {
          setgameData(response.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
      });
  }
```

I know that the screen that is meant to show the game data has the GUID, because it is displayed on the screen. When the displayed GUID is entered into a Postman request, I get the data I expect.

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

EDIT: The following is the Axios response the app provides me:

```
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:15:17 in createError
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:16:9 in settle
- node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:53:6 in handleLoad
- node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:592:4 in setReadyState
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:395:6 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

3030-16836

Request failed with status code 404
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:15:17 in createError
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:16:9 in settle
- node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:53:6 in handleLoad
- node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:592:4 in setReadyState
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:395:6 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Comment: is it possible that you are passing some sort of token in postman and you are not doing that here? also, have you considered that maybe something is different in the header of the request?

Comment: @MasoudTahmasebi I'm fairly sure I'm not passing anything in Postman that I'm not passing in the app, but how would I check?

Comment: you can go to the headers section, and then on the right, there's the orange "Code" text which can be clicked and it will show you all the headers which have been set. Also, you are using an "[API_KEY]" as a string here, maybe you have added the value there. maybe the axious response can also be helpful

Comment: @MasoudTahmasebi I haven't applied any headers in Postman. The [API_KEY] in the post is just obfuscating the actual API key from the code, which is directly entered into the request URL for debug purposes. I've added the Axios response to the post now.

Comment: why do you have {} brackets around gameId?

Comment: Use string interpolation like this: `https://www.giantbomb.com/api/game/${gameId}/?api_key=[API_KEY]`

Also `https://www.giantbomb.com/api/game/${gameId}/?api_key=[API_KEY]` and `https://www.giantbomb.com/api/game/${gameId}?api_key=[API_KEY]` might not be the same. Do you have a trailing slash in Postman?

Comment: as others have suggested, maybe you have to change URL to: url: "https://www.giantbomb.com/api/game/"+gameId+"/?api_key=[API_KEY]"

Comment: Those brackets would create an object `{ gameId: gameId }` which would then be stringified into `[object Object]`. I doubt that's a valid URL.

Comment: @spijs This is it! A stupid mistake; no wonder it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenters have pointed out (thanks @MinusFour @MasoudTahmasebi @spijs) the problem was a simple syntax mistake involving misplaced {}. Thanks all of you!